# ColdFusion 8 access to MySQL database without datasource

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

My webhosting doesn't allow us to access and modify the datasource, but having CF8, anyone have done access to mysql before?

Do I need to use PHP?

Comment: Not really an answer, but have you asked the hosting provider WHY can't you have a datasource, if you have both CF and MySQL? This is totally stupid and would make me think about changing the provider.

Comment: Yap, I going to confirm with them again, but in *shared hosting*, each webmaster if given the ability to login to CF admin control panel, will we see other webmaster's database in the datasource?

Comment: They won't typically give you access to CFAdmin in a shared situation, but they should create your datasource for you.

Comment: Good suggestion, I ask them now, hope it work this way to by connect datasource to MySQL

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you could do it using Mark Mandel's JavaLoader and MySQL Connector, but no way you could work with it normally :(

Probably it would be better if you write what you'd like to do, maybe you could do that some other way which doesn't require access to CF administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you take advantage of CF 8s application.cfc settings?  [Reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=appFramework_03.html)  This should allow you to do what you have to do.  Additionally you can actually get at the underlying java objects. [This](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1686-Accessing-ColdFusion-Application-Settings.htm) Web page should point you in the right direction.

Comment: To clear up, they said Plesk control panel could automatically connect CF DSN to MySQL db

Answer (score 0):

To clear up, they said Plesk control panel could automatically connect CF DSN to MySQL db